# What is the largest cycle of RSA encryption?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Is there a maximum length of a message before it is impractical to use RSA?

Comment: It's always impractical to use RSA. Why is why it's only ever used to encrypt keys.

Comment: The efficiency issue in practice depends on the specific application requirements (and also on the implementation). There are always trade-offs. If you require extremely fast encrpytion, then you have to use a block cipher to do the main encryption work and let RSA only to transfer a secret key of the block cipher. However, for the general low-volume normal communications of the common people, encryption processing time of the order of a couple of seconds is certainly entirely acceptable and RSA can be directly used to do the encryption. (See my code s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but this question is unanswerable as it stands. What is "practical" totally depends on the requirements. @Sekou: Could you clarify what you mean by "practical"? Otherwise this question should probably be closed.